# Conversion of SimpleDateFormat patterns to Java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, simpledateformat

Is there any tool or library or suggested approach for generically converting a date pattern string (e.g., "dd-mm-yyyy"), as defined by the `SimpleDateFormat` class, into a `Java` regular expression?

There are many examples in the web (some in Stack Overflow) that "manually" derive a regex from a specific date pattern, but apparently no implementation exists for any automated approach (i.e., writing a parser that does the conversion).

The `SimpleDateFormat` class has a `compile()` method which converts the string date pattern into a character array and not a regular expressions, possibly because it predates the introduction of the java.util.regex package in the Java distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there's no automated conversion is because the conversion would simply replace the `d`s `m`s and `y`s with `\d`.  For the case of month and day names, yes, regex might be somewhat more useful, but it's not really suited to that particular task; you'd have a group such as `(Jan|Feb|...|Dec)`.  Regex is great and finding patterns but NOT great at validating the data in those patterns.

If you were really dead set on using regex, as an example you could look for `dd` in the string and replace that with `(?:[0-2]\d|3[01])`; what that regex group doesn't guarantee is that the specified month allows 31 days.

Comment: All this is very reasonable (and +1), but what if you want to assess whether a random string is a date? Then you definitely need a regular expression.

Comment: Then you need a whole battery of regular expressions or one really, really messy one; `16 May 2014`, `2014/05/16`,  `05-16-2014` and `May 16, 2014` are all valid ways (although not even close to the only ways) to express today's date.  You also can't easily validate the date (ie: February 31, 34 BC).

Comment: Precisely! Many regular expressions are needed, which is why it would be much easier if there was a tool to automatically generate them from all the SimpleDateFormat patterns. Date detection from string can be done without exact matching.

Comment: As stated above the date could be in any number of formats, with or without punctuation, numbers, words, a combination thereof, you'd have to use the common formatting of the machine's locale etc.  A better approach would be to tokenize your input and then look for specific patterns in sequence, such as 1 of: 2 digits with a value of 31 or less, 3 letters which then get validated for a short month + the max number of days, then 4 digits.  Regex requires an expected input and you really don't know what might be coming here.

Comment: Yes, but the combinations are many and it would be easier if there was an automated way of generating the code.

Comment: If you ignore order then the combinations are far fewer (ie: when you find a token that matches one of the categories, check the next token for one of the appropriate remaining types (ie:  `December` and `Dec` side by side would fail this check but `December` and `12` would not) and then check for the third appropriate type (in this case, you're looking for a year, so `December`, `12`, `12` should be accepted even though it may not make any sense in your context, in which case you'll want to then validate the date text you've detected).  No simple solutions for what you're after.

Comment: Yes, it is complicated. Thanks!